# Spark sql: string to timestamp conversion: value changing to NULL

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I've an issue with Spark SQL, where the column type if I typecast from string to timestamp, the value becomes NULL. Below are the details:

```
val df2 = sql("""select FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(to_date(LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(CONCAT_WS('-','2018','10','01'),0))),'yyyy-MM-dd'),'yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss')""")
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(to_date(last_day(add_months(CAST(concat_ws(-, 2018, 10, 01) AS DATE), 0))), yyyy-MM-dd), yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss): string]


scala> df2.show
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(to_date(last_day(add_months(CAST(concat_ws(-, 2018, 10, 01) AS DATE), 0))), yyyy-MM-dd), yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss)|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                                                                       20181001 00:00:00|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

When typecasting to timestamp explicitly, it won't give me the desired result.

```
val df2 = sql("""select cast(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(to_date(LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(CONCAT_WS('-','2018','10','01'),0))),'yyyy-MM-dd'),'yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss') as timestamp)""")
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [CAST(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(to_date(last_day(add_months(CAST(concat_ws(-, 2018, 10, 01) AS DATE), 0))), yyyy-MM-dd), yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss) AS TIMESTAMP): timestamp]


scala> df2.show
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|CAST(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(to_date(last_day(add_months(CAST(concat_ws(-, 2018, 10, 01) AS DATE), 0))), yyyy-MM-dd), yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss) AS TIMESTAMP)|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                                                                                                       null|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Any idea to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it like this, without using any spark internals.

```
val df2 = sql("""cast(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(cast(LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(CONCAT_WS('-','2018','12','31'),0)) as timestamp))) as timestamp)""")

scala> df2.show
+--------------------+
|2018-12-31 00:00:...|
+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
val df2 = spark.sql(
      """select CAST(unix_timestamp(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(to_date(LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(CONCAT_WS('-','2018','10','01'),0))),'yyyy-MM-dd'),'yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss'),'yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss') as timestamp) as destination""".stripMargin)

df2.show(false)
df2.printSchema()

+-------------------+
|destination        |
+-------------------+
|2018-10-31 00:00:00|
+-------------------+

root
 |-- destination: timestamp (nullable = true)
```